# Pandoc document conversion failed with erro 127

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, shiny-server

I have a problem with RMarkDown-Scripts that are stored in the `~/ShinyApps` folder of my Shiny server.

The RMarkDown file fails to build in RStudio as well as in the web browser. The error message is always the same:

```
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 127
In addition: Warning message:
In system(command) : system call failed: No child processes
Execution halted
Warning message:
system call failed: No child processes
```

The strange thing is that sometimes the build process works and the document will be displayed correctly. Usually, RStudio generates the HTML file before the pandoc error appears.

Here is a simple RMarkDown file that sometimes will lead to the `pandoc document conversion failed` error message:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Marco Nae"
date: "25 February 2016"
output: html_document
---

Text.

```{r}
print("R code")
```

Text

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

The system is CentOs.

Can anyone provide assistance?